# how to make flex scanner switch to new string after parsing failure

Tags: parsing, bison, reset, lex, restart

this is part of my toy porject:a web server
I need to parse http requests using parser based on flex and bison
when the request is valid,it works well.But when there is a parsing failure,it can't parse subsequent requeset any more:in effect,it doesn't parse the new requeset,but pick up where it fails
such as:

```
Accepted connection from (localhost, 11578)
4 says :GET /BAD/ HTTP/1.1
4 says :Host: www.baidu.com
4 says :
t:token_char G
token: Matched rule 1.
t:token_char E
token: Matched rule 2.
t:token_char T
token: Matched rule 2.
t:sp ' '; 
t:backslash; 
text: Matched rule 1.
t:token_char B
OWS: Matched rule 1
text: Matched rule 2.
t:token_char A
OWS: Matched rule 1
text: Matched rule 2.
t:token_char D
OWS: Matched rule 1
text: Matched rule 2.
t:backslash; 
OWS: Matched rule 1
text: Matched rule 2.
t:sp ' '; 
t:token_char H
text: Matched rule 1.
t:token_char T
OWS: Matched rule 1
text: Matched rule 2.
t:token_char T
OWS: Matched rule 1
text: Matched rule 2.
t:token_char P
OWS: Matched rule 1
text: Matched rule 2.
t:backslash; 
OWS: Matched rule 1
text: Matched rule 2.
t:digit 1; 
OWS: Matched rule 1
text: Matched rule 2.
t:dot; 
OWS: Matched rule 1
text: Matched rule 2.
t:digit 1; 
OWS: Matched rule 1
text: Matched rule 2.
t:ctl
OWS: Matched rule 1
syntax error, unexpected t_ctl
Parsing Failed
not valid
Accepted connection from (localhost, 11579)
5 says :GET /GOOD/ HTTP/1.1
5 says :Host: www.baidu.com
5 says :
t:token_char H
token: Matched rule 1.
t:token_char o
token: Matched rule 2.
t:token_char s
token: Matched rule 2.
t:token_char t
token: Matched rule 2.
t:colon; 
syntax error, unexpected t_colon, expecting t_digit or t_dot or t_token_char or t_sp
Parsing Failed
not valid
```

i tried a lot of methods,but somewhat they just didn't work:

```
        // BEGIN INITIAL;
        FILE * fp=fmemopen(buf,i,"r");
        yyrestart(fp);
        set_parsing_options(buf, i, request);
        // yyreset(YY_BUFFER_STATE);
        // yy_flush_buffer();
        if (yyparse() == SUCCESS)
        {
            return request;
        }
        // yylex_destroy(); doesn't work
```

like this
the lexer.l:

```
%{
#include <unistd.h>

/* This file is generated by yacc */
#include "y.tab.h"


/* Define LEXDEBUG to enable debug messages for this lex file */
#define LEXDEBUG 1
#ifdef LEXDEBUG
#include <stdio.h>
#define LPRINTF(...) printf(__VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define LPRINTF(...)
#endif

#undef YY_INPUT
/*
 * yylex() by default takes input from stdin. You might be wondering how
 * to parse data from a buffer instead. This is how you do it. The way
 * it works is, when yylex() needs more input, it invokes a macro
 * called YYINPUT:
 *
 * YY_INPUT(lex_internal_buffer, number_of_bytes_read, max_number_of_bytes_to_read)
 *
 * We hack it, and we undef the macro, and redefine it to something else!
 *
 * The usage of this macro will be clear from the lex-yacc-example.??????我知道啥
 */

/* We need some global state (must be defined in parser.y) */
extern char *parsing_buf;   /* The buffer to read the data from */
extern size_t parsing_buf_siz;  /* Size of the buffer */
extern int parsing_offset;  /* Current offset in the buffer */

#define MIN(__a, __b) (((__a) < (__b)) ? (__a) : (__b))

/* Redefine YY_INPUT to read from a buffer instead of stdin! */
#define YY_INPUT(__b, __r, __s) do {                    \
        __r = MIN(__s, parsing_buf_siz - parsing_offset);   \
        memcpy(__b, parsing_buf + parsing_offset, __r);     \
        parsing_offset += __r;                  \
    } while(0)



%}

/*
 * Following is a list of rules specified in RFC 2616 section 2:
 *
 * Lookup Table
 * cr              \x0d
 * lf              \x0a
 * sp              \x20
 * ht              \x09
 * quote           \"
 * digit           [0-9]
 * ctl             [\x0-\x1f\x7f]
 * upalpha         [A-Z]
 * loalpha         [a-z]
 * alpha       [A-Za-z]
 * char            [\x0-\x7f]
 * octet           [\x0-\x1f\xff]
 * crlf            {cr}{lf}
 * lws             \x0d\x0a(\x20|\x09)*
 * hex             [ABCDEFabcdef0-9]
 * separators      [\{\}\(\)\<\>@,;:\\\"/\[\]?=\x20\x09]
 */

/**
 * Declarations
 */

/* Matches a digit. For e.g., 0, 8. */
digit       [0-9]

/* Matches a CRLF. Carriage return - linefeed sequence */
crlf            \x0d\x0a

/* Matches a Colon */
colon           :

/* Matches a space */
sp      \x20

/* Matches a any combination of spaces and horizontal tabs */
ws      [\x20\x09]*

/* Matches a CRLF followed by a ws */
lws             \x0d\x0a(\x20|\x09)*

/*
 * matches following characters: (RFC 2616, Section 2.2)
 * ( ) < > @ , ; : \ " / [ ] ? = { } <space> <tab>
 */
separators  [\(\)\<\>@\,;:\\\"/\[\]?=\{\}\x20\x09]

/* Matches a CTL*/
ctl [\x0-\x1f\x7f]

/*
 * (RFC 2616, Section 2.2)
 * This rule matches _ANY_ character _EXCEPT_ separators (see above),
 * and control characters (ascii values 0x0 - 0x1F and 0x7f).
 *
 * token_char = (   char    -       ctl      -               separators             )
 *
 * Note: A token can be detected as any combination of token characters.
 */
token_char      [\x0-\x7f]{-}[\x0-\x1f\x7f]{-}[\{\}\(\)\<\>@\,;:\\\"/\[\]?=\x20\x09]

%%
%{
/*
 * Actions
 *
 * yytext: yytext is the "string" that matches a certain rule. For example,
 *         in the first rule 1: backslash, you get the string that matched
 *         (in this case "/") in yytext.
 *
 * yylval: yylval is a variable used to communicate matched value in lex to
 *         yacc. yylval is a union of different types (please see parser.y)
 *         file for details.
 */
%}

"/" {
    /* Rule 1: Backslash */

    LPRINTF("t:backslash; \n");

    /* Copy character to yylval.i*/
    yylval.i = yytext[0];

    /*
     * This return statement lets terminates yylex() function and lets
     * yacc know that a backslash was found!
     */
    return t_backslash;
}

{crlf} {
    /* Rule 2: CRLF */

    LPRINTF("t:crlf; \n");

    /*
     * No need to communicate the value of CRLF to yacc, so no
     * yylval here.
     */

    return t_crlf;
}

{sp} {
    /* Rule 3: Space */

    LPRINTF("t:sp '%s'; \n", yytext);

    yylval.i = yytext[0];

    return t_sp;
}

{ws} {
    /* Rule 4: A sequence of white spaces */

    LPRINTF("t:ht; \n");

    /* Very important to communicate the value here! */
    strcpy(yylval.str, yytext);

    return t_ws;
}

{digit} {
    /* Rule 5: A digit */

    LPRINTF("t:digit %d; \n", atoi(yytext));

    yylval.i = atoi(yytext);

    return t_digit;
}

"." {
    /* Rule 6: A dot */

    LPRINTF("t:dot; \n");
    yylval.i = '.';
    return t_dot;
}

{colon} {
    /* Rule 7: A colon */

    LPRINTF("t:colon; \n");
    yylval.i = ':';
    return t_colon;
}

{separators} {
    /* Rule 8: A separator */

    LPRINTF("t:separators \'%s\'\n", yytext);
    yylval.i = yytext[0];
    return t_separators;
}

{token_char} {
    /* Rule 9: A character allowed in a token */

    LPRINTF("t:token_char %s\n", yytext);
    /*
     * Again, it is important to communicate the value back
     * Otherwise, yacc has no way to know which character matched the rule
     */
    yylval.i = yytext[0];
    return t_token_char;
}

{lws} {
    /* Rule 10: Linear white spaces */

    LPRINTF("t:lws\n");
    return t_lws;
}

{ctl} {
    LPRINTF("t:ctl\n");
    return t_ctl;
}

%%

int yywrap(void) {
return 0; }
```

the parser.y:

```
%{
#include "parse.h"

/* Define YACCDEBUG to enable debug messages for this lex file */
#define YACCDEBUG 1
//for debug
// #define YYDEBUG 1
#define YYERROR_VERBOSE
#ifdef YACCDEBUG
#include <stdio.h>
#define YPRINTF(...) printf(__VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define YPRINTF(...)
#endif

/* yyparse() calls yyerror() on error */
void yyerror (char *s);

void set_parsing_options(char *buf, size_t siz, Request *parsing_request);

/* yyparse() calls yylex() to get tokens */
extern int yylex();
// extern yyin; // 好像不能在这里restart

/*
** Global variables required for parsing from buffer
** instead of stdin:
*/

/* Pointer to the buffer that contains input */
char *parsing_buf;

/* Current position in the buffer */
int parsing_offset;

/* Buffer size */
size_t parsing_buf_siz;

/* Current parsing_request Header Struct */
Request *parsing_request;

%}


/* Various types values that we can get from lex */
%union {
    char str[8192];
    int i;
}

%start request

/*
 * Tokens that yacc expects from lex, essentially these are the tokens
 * declared in declaration section of lex file.
 */
%token t_crlf
%token t_backslash
%token t_digit
%token t_dot
%token t_token_char
%token t_lws
%token t_colon
%token t_separators
%token t_sp
%token t_ws
%token t_ctl

/* Type of value returned for these tokens */
%type<str> t_crlf
%type<i> t_backslash
%type<i> t_digit
%type<i> t_dot
%type<i> t_token_char
%type<str> t_lws
%type<i> t_colon
%type<i> t_separators
%type<i> t_sp
%type<str> t_ws
%type<i> t_ctl

/*
 * Followed by this, you should have types defined for all the intermediate
 * rules that you will define. These are some of the intermediate rules:
 */
%type<i> allowed_char_for_token
%type<i> allowed_char_for_text
%type<str> ows
%type<str> token
%type<str> text

%%

/*
** The following 2 rules define a token.
*/

/*
 * Rule 1: Allowed characters in a token
 *
 * An excerpt from RFC 2616:
 * --
 * token          = 1*<any CHAR except CTLs or separators>
 * --
 */
allowed_char_for_token:
t_token_char; |
t_digit {
    $$ = '0' + $1;
}; |
t_dot;

/*
 * Rule 2: A token is a sequence of all allowed token chars.
 */
token:
allowed_char_for_token {
    YPRINTF("token: Matched rule 1.\n");
    snprintf($$, 8192, "%c", $1);
}; |
token allowed_char_for_token {
    YPRINTF("token: Matched rule 2.\n");
  snprintf($$, 8192, "%s%c", $1, $2);
};

/*
** The following 2 rules define text.
*/
/*
 *
 * Rule 3: Allowed characters in text
 *
 * An excerpt from RFC 2616, section 2.2:
 * --
 * The TEXT rule is only used for descriptive field contents and values
 * that are not intended to be interpreted by the message parser. Words
 * of *TEXT MAY contain characters from character sets other than ISO-
 * 8859-1 [22] only when encoded according to the rules of RFC 2047
 * [14].
 *
 * TEXT = <any OCTET except CTLs, but including LWS>
 * --
 *
 */

allowed_char_for_text:
allowed_char_for_token; |
t_separators {
    $$ = $1;
}; |
t_colon {
    $$ = $1;
}; |
t_backslash {
    $$ = $1;
};

/*
 * Rule 4: Text is a sequence of characters allowed in text as per RFC. May
 *     also contains spaces.
 */
text: allowed_char_for_text {
    YPRINTF("text: Matched rule 1.\n");
    snprintf($$, 8192, "%c", $1);
}; |
text ows allowed_char_for_text {
    YPRINTF("text: Matched rule 2.\n");
    snprintf($$, 8192, "%s%s%c", $1, $2, $3);
};

/*
 * Rule 5: Optional white spaces
 */
ows: {
    YPRINTF("OWS: Matched rule 1\n");
    $$[0]=0;
}; |
t_sp {
    YPRINTF("OWS: Matched rule 2\n");
    snprintf($$, 8192, "%c", $1);
}; |
t_ws {
    YPRINTF("OWS: Matched rule 3\n");
    snprintf($$, 8192, "%s", $1);
};

request_line: token t_sp text t_sp text t_crlf {
    YPRINTF("request_Line:\n%s\n%s\n%s\n",$1, $3,$5);
    strcpy(parsing_request->http_method, $1);
    strcpy(parsing_request->http_uri, $3);
    strcpy(parsing_request->http_version, $5);
}

request_header: token ows t_colon ows text ows t_crlf {
    YPRINTF("request_Header:\n%s\n%s\n",$1,$5);
    strcpy(parsing_request->headers[parsing_request->header_count].header_name, $1);
    strcpy(parsing_request->headers[parsing_request->header_count].header_value, $5);
    parsing_request->header_count++;
}

// request_headers:request_header;
//              | request_headers request_header{
//                  parsing_request->headers=(Request_header *)realloc(parsing_request->headers,parsing_request->header_count);
//                  // strcpy(parsing_request->headers[parsing_request->header_count].header_name, $2->);
//                  // strcpy(parsing_request->headers[parsing_request->header_count].header_value, $2);
//                  parsing_request->header_count++;
//              }


/*
 * You need to fill this rule, and you are done! You have all the assembly
 * needed. You may wish to define your own rules. Please read RFC 2616
 * and the annotated excerpted text on the course website. All the best!
 *
 */
request: request_line request_header t_crlf{
    YPRINTF("parsing_request: Matched Success.\n");
    return SUCCESS;
};

%%

/* C code */

void set_parsing_options(char *buf, size_t siz, Request *request)
{
    parsing_buf = buf;
    parsing_offset = 0;
    parsing_buf_siz = siz;
    parsing_request = request;
}

void yyerror (char *s) 
{
    fprintf (stderr, "%s\n", s);
    // yyrestart(yyin);
    // YY_FLUSH_BUFFER();
    // yy_flush_buffer();
}
```

the parse function:

```
#include "parse.h"

/**
* Given a char buffer returns the parsed request headers
*/
// extern int yylex_destroy(); doesn't work
// extern yyin;//doesn't work
// extern YY_BUFFER_STATE;
// extern yyreset();
extern void yyrestart(FILE *);
Request *parse(char *buffer, int size, int socketFd)
{
    //Differant states in the state machine
    enum
    {
        STATE_START = 0,
        STATE_CR,
        STATE_CRLF,
        STATE_CRLFCR,
        STATE_CRLFCRLF
    };

    int i = 0, state;
    size_t offset = 0;
    char ch;
    char buf[8192];
    memset(buf, 0, 8192);

    state = STATE_START;
    while (state != STATE_CRLFCRLF)
    {
        char expected = 0;

        if (i == size)
            break;

        ch = buffer[i++];
        buf[offset++] = ch;

        switch (state)
        {
        case STATE_START:
        case STATE_CRLF:
            expected = '\r';
            break;
        case STATE_CR:
        case STATE_CRLFCR:
            expected = '\n';
            break;
        default:
            state = STATE_START;
            continue;
        }

        if (ch == expected)
            state++;
        // 下面这个设置很重要，这样就保证了只有连续的\r\n\r\n,才能达到最终状态
        // 分开的两个\r\n是不能的
        else
            state = STATE_START;
    }

    //Valid End State
    if (state == STATE_CRLFCRLF)
    {
        Request *request = (Request *)malloc(sizeof(Request));
        request->header_count = 0;
        //TODO You will need to handle resizing this in parser.y
        // 这个resizing是不是可以在这里修改，直接在malloc时，根据上面\r\n出现的次数
        // 然后-1（request line）,-2(\r\n\r\n in the end)?TODO
        request->headers = (Request_header *)malloc(sizeof(Request_header) * 1);
        // BEGIN INITIAL;
        FILE * fp=fmemopen(buf,i,"r");
        yyrestart(fp);
        set_parsing_options(buf, i, request);
        // yyreset(YY_BUFFER_STATE);
        // yy_flush_buffer();
        if (yyparse() == SUCCESS)
        {
            return request;
        }
        // yylex_destroy(); doesn't work
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "don't pass the state machine\n");
    }
    //TODO Handle Malformed Requests
    printf("Parsing Failed\n");
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Most of that code was given to you, right?

Comment: yes,the comment in parser.y says I need to fill  a rule,but that rule is for multi-header requeset,so I think it doesn't matter now

Comment: I tried restart,yyset etc,in the parse function,but I'm not sure whether I use them the right way,and so far none of them worked

Comment: my point was that I suspect you didn't write the `YY_INPUT` macro. Do you understand what it does? Are you allowed to change it? (You need to say in the question what parts of the code you wrote and what parts you are allowed to change. Otherwise it's hard to make good suggestions.)

Comment: #define YY_INPUT(__b, __r, __s) do {                    \
        __r = MIN(__s, parsing_buf_siz - parsing_offset);   \
        memcpy(__b, parsing_buf + parsing_offset, __r);     \
        parsing_offset += __r;                  \
    } while(0)

Comment: in the parser.y ,it redefines the YY_INPUT.Yes I am doing a assignment for a cmu network course,but I didn't attend class actually,I learn by self-study,so I probably can't find a prof to ask for

Comment: I don't really understand how the YY_INPUT work....I think I can change the parser.y and  parse function a little.Yes I realized that's probably hard to give suggestion,maybe I should read some doc about flex and bison?I read a book on flex and bison by john levine,which is pretty good,but i haven't read it all,and I don't whether it can help me on this question

Comment: yes,this code is from cmu 15441,project1,checkpoint1....yes ,that book is pretty good,but the way the base code was wrtitten confused me

Comment: OK, I wrote something by way of an answer and moved some of my comments into it. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

#### Contextual note

I eventually tracked down the bulk of the code presented in this question to starter code for [Project 1 of CMU course 15-441/641](https://computer-networks.github.io/sp19/assignments.html), which is a networking course rather than a parsing course. (As of today, the supplied code can be found [here](https://github.com/computer-networks/sp19/tree/master/projects) in various versions, but I don't expect that link to last.)

The assignment says, in part:

> Historical evidence suggests that most students spend considerable amount of time writing correct parsers. While parsing packets using C’s string manipulation functions may well be an essential skill to have, it might get insanely tedious. We want you to spend time on other more important programming aspects such as socket programming, handling race conditions and memory leaks. For this reason, we require you to use Lex and Yacc for parsing packets. We will also provide you with a basic HTTP parser written in lex and yacc.

If the course designers were sincere about that point, one might think that they would have provided a *well-written* HTTP parser. But the supplied parser is not well-written, nor is it robust, nor is it complete. Nor is it even correct, and at least one error (the backslash pattern) seems designed to force the student to find and correct it.

Personally, I wouldn't use the code, even as a basis, and it seems to me that a student who intends to learn parsing theory as well as networking might have good motivation to write their own parser, possibly using flex/bison although it's not clear to me that these are the optimal tools for this particular parsing task. But that might not be good advice for a student enrolled in a course, and particularly while doing an assignment with a deadline.

Since the assignment seems to be insistent on the student doing the work themselves (TAs not being allowed to touch a keyboard during consultations, etc.), I have avoided correcting all the errors in the supplied code, focusing on the particular issue of how to supply a text buffer to flex.

#### Flex does provide mechanisms to take input from a buffer. Use them.

The starter code includes the following comment:

```
/*
 * yylex() by default takes input from stdin. You might be wondering how
 * to parse data from a buffer instead. This is how you do it. The way
 * it works is, when yylex() needs more input, it invokes a macro
 * called YYINPUT:
 ...
 */
```

The code that follows is *not* the recommended way to parse data from a buffer, since a flex-generated scanner provides various interfaces designed specifically
to parse text from a character array without in any way modifying the scanner description.

It's important to understand what a flex buffer is. It is not an input source, exactly; rather, it is precisely an abstraction for a memory buffer which contains data obtained from the input source. The flex buffer also contains information about the progress of the input operation necessary for the scan, including the location of the start of the next token, the current line number (and possibly column number) corresponding to that location, and the `FILE*` to be used to obtain more data (which might not actually be used). When you call `yylex()`, if there is a current flex buffer, the next token will be obtained from the current position in that buffer. If there is not a current buffer, a new buffer will be created using `yyin` as an input source.

Replacing `yyin` will have no effect on the scan if there is a current buffer. But replacing the current buffer with a new buffer, or deleting the current buffer, will have immediate effect.

The flex-generated scanner provides several interfaces which can be used to manipulate flex buffers, which are described in the [flex manual chapter on input buffers](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Multiple-Input-Buffers.html), which you should read for more information. The specific interfaces which can be used to scan data already read into memory are described at the end of that chapter. There are three of them, with slight differences, but if you already know the length of the data (and in this case you do know it) then there is no point using the interface which calls `strlen()` to recompute that length. (Also, calling `strlen()` is not correct if the data might contain NULs.)

The remaining two interfaces differ in that one of them makes an internal copy of the input data, whereas the other one simply uses the supplied data. When writing network servers, it's usually a good idea to avoid copying strings whenever possible, but it's important to understand the consequences of not making a copy:

1. If the data is not copied, the caller is responsible for not modifying the storage until the scan is complete, which might involve a number of calls to yylex.
2. The flex-generated scanner modifies the input data during the scan. So once the data is handed over to flex, its contents can no longer be relied upon. Also, the data given to flex cannot be a string literal or other immutable storage.
3. In the particular case of flex, the flex-generated scanner requires that the data to be scan be followed by two (!) NUL bytes, which are not part of the data stream. If you are assembling a character array to give to flex this is not a huge problem, because you can make the array two bytes longer than necessary and clear the trailing bytes to 0. But if you are trying to use a buffer directly read from a file, this can be problematic.

So it may be easier to use the interface which makes a copy of the data:

```
YY_BUFFER_STATE yy_scan_bytes ( const char *bytes, int len )
```

This function returns the `YY_BUFFER_STATE` which it creates, but it also deletes the current flex buffer and installs the buffer it creates as the current flex buffer. So you don't actually need to save the returned value but you should check that the return value is not NULL, which would indicate an error (probably related to memory allocation).

If you want to avoid the copy, you can use

```
YY_BUFFER_STATE yy_scan_buffer (char *base, yy_size_t size)
```

which does exactly the same thing, but without making a copy. Note that the supplied data must be *followed* by two NUL bytes, which are not part of the data to be scanned. `size` is the actual size of the buffer including these two NUL bytes, so you usually end up doing something like `yy_scan_buffer(data, datalen + 2);`

Again, it is important that the return value be checked for the error case. `yy_scan_buffer` verifies that the supplied buffer ends with two NULs, and returns NULL if they are not present. (If `yy_scan_buffer` returns NULL, it also sets `YY_CURRENT_BUFFER` to `NULL` so that the next scan will read from `yyin`. That's almost certainly not what you want.)

Comment: well....I don't know ,somehow,I use yyrestart(NULL) before yyparse() and it works..

Comment: And with some effort,I kind of complete the first stage work,like parsing requeset with multiple header

Comment: anyway,really appreciate your help and effort

Comment: I agree. *flex* and *bison* are the last tools I would use to parse HTTP. You don't need anything much more sophisticated than a line reader until you get to attachments.